# Как отправить фото с текстом

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пользователь пишет "детективы" и бот должен ответить ему текстом вместе с картинкой, как это сделать? В чем ошибка в моем коде? (aiogram 3)
(так же выводит ошибку: `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile without an implementation for abstract method 'read'`) - искал решение в интернете/ИИ, правильного решения я к сожалению не нашёл

```
@router.message(F.text.lower() == "детективы")
async def msg_detective(message: Message):
    photo_input_file = types.InputFile('https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/reinebringen-mountains-in-norway-b5.jpg')
    await message.reply_photo(photo=photo_input_file, caption='TEST')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```py
@router.message(F.text.lower() == "детективы")
async def msg_detective(message: Message):
        await message.answer_photo('https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/reinebringen-mountains-in-norway-b5.jpg', caption='TEST')
```

Результат:
[image: Результат]

Возникнут вопросы - пиши в коменты

P.s. Рекомендую сохранить картинку из интернета, потому что картинку могут удалить. (Мало ли что произойдет на сайте)